# Possible to mute irrelevant error messages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, error-handling

If I erroneously would call a private method in the console, I'm getting 25 lines of error messages like the following:

```
from /Users/Omonia/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
```

The first line normally gives meaningful information but the rest could easily be muted.

Is there any way to clean this up?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the standard IRB REPL as rails console, adding the following line :

```
IRB.conf[:BACK_TRACE_LIMIT] = 1
```

to your `~/.irbrc` file truncates the output to the desired limit.

However I would advise against doing so, because error backtraces can be immensely helpful in complex debugging cases.